# How to spyOn a global function and return a value in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine2.0

How can I spy on `MyFunction` and return `2` in Jasmine 2.0?

I have the following code that errors on the first line inside `shouldPass` with:

> `Error: function MyFunction(){ return 1; }() method does not exist`

It appears to be using the entire function as the function name

MyFile.js:

```
MyFunctionToTest = function(){
    return MyFunction() + 1;
}

function MyFunction(){ return 1; }
```

MyFileSpec.js:

```
describe("myTest", function(){
    it("shouldPass", function(){
        spyOn("MyFile", MyFunction).and.returnValue(2);

        expect(MyFunctionToTest()).toEqual(3)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to spy on an anonymous/global function. You can probably just redefine it with a spy.

```
MyFunction = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(2);
```